# querying a key - value pair table with conditionals

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I've been stumped on this one and would appreciate any help.

Here is the structure of the table:

```
+----+-------------+-------------------+--+
| id |    name     |       value       |  |
+----+-------------+-------------------+--+
|  3 | email       | dsflkej@gmail.com |  |
|  3 | device_type | iOS               |  |
|  3 | text        | purchase          |  |
|  4 | email       | ueif@gmail.com    |  |
|  4 | device_type | iOS               |  |
|  5 | email       | tckjef@gmail.com  |  |
|  5 | device_type | Android           |  |
|  5 | text        | where can i pur   |  |
+----+-------------+-------------------+--+
```

I would like a result that looks like this:

```
╔════╦══════╦═════════════════╦══╦══╗
║ id ║ name ║      value      ║  ║  ║
╠════╬══════╬═════════════════╬══╬══╣
║  3 ║ text ║ purchase        ║  ║  ║
║  4 ║ text ║ Null            ║  ║  ║
║  5 ║ text ║ where can i pur ║  ║  ║
╚════╩══════╩═════════════════╩══╩══╝
```

Because of the structure of the data in k/v pairs, I'm having trouble finding the right logic to grab unique id's and then the row where the name = text along with the value of text. When a row with the name text does not appear for an id, I would like to still keep that id but show that it doesn't exist.

Comment: thanks @JustinCave I've re-edited entries from Text to text to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8c140/4)

```
select id, 'text', min(decode(name, 'text',value)) 
  from table1 
group by id
order by 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8c140/4/0)**:

```
| ID | 'TEXT' | MIN(DECODE(NAME,'TEXT',VALUE)) |
|----|--------|--------------------------------|
|  3 |   text |                       purchase |
|  4 |   text |                         (null) |
|  5 |   text |                where can i pur |
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be something like this.  I'm getting the distinct ID values from the table in the `WITH` clause and then left joining back to the table to get the data.

```
WITH distinct_ids 
  AS( SELECT DISTINCT id
        FROM your_table )
SELECT ids.id,
       nvl(tbl.name,'text'),
       tbl.value
  FROM distinct_ids ids
       LEFT OUTER JOIN your_table tbl
         ON(     ids.id = tbl.id
             AND tbl.name = 'text' )
```